# ngOptions preselecting option not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

say we have this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.playList.Videos.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.playList.Videos[i].Id == $scope.video.Id) index = i;
}
$scope.playList.currentVideo = index + 1;
$scope.playList.selectedVideo = $scope.playList.Videos[index];
$scope.playList.totalVideos = $scope.playList.Videos.length;
```

so as you can see, the playlist has some videos, and there is a video object that is in that list.
than it sets some values like the `current video index` and `current video` via the index found.

but when I do the following:

```
<select class="selectVideo" ng-options="vid as playList.Videos.indexOf(vid)+1 for vid in playList.Videos track by video.Id" ng-model="playList.selectedVideo" class="browser-default"></select>
```

it doesn't select my video, I tried it via Id, index, ...
but none seem to do what I want.

any clue why?

Comment: Could you provide the fiddle for this? Did you try removing the track by?

Comment: You are tracking the options by the video id but the model is a video object. I don't understand why you do the as playList.Videos.indexOf(vid) + 1, this increments the id of the options and won't match i think. Why not to use vid.Title as vid.Id? Hopes this help

Comment: That's because the way the database is build , I only have access to the Id, so I had to make the decision, preform a query for getting the names, or just show Id. and for now this was good enougn